# Vincular archivo en toda la web desde su carpeta raiz

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un archivo llamado "busqueda.php" dicho archivo esta en una carpeta llamada "Skins"

La idea es que el header.php tome ese archivo de esa carpeta, siendo que este en cualquier parte de la web, hasta donde tengo entendido usar / al principio lleva a la carpeta raíz.

Ya de por si el "header.php" contiene el " y el "<?php include("/Skin/busqueda.php");"

ejemplo del erro...

(/BD/conexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\Categorias\Conexiones\Medidas\Abrazadera\CaEsc\busqueda.php on line 1

Comment: Por lo que veo es una máquina WIndows. ¿Probaste usando \ en vez de / como divisor de ruta?

Comment: tienes que usar ../ parra ir moviendote de posicion hacia atras, asi vas encontrando correctamente tu ruta

Comment: Si, probé usando la barra invertida "\ " y aun así no funciona, el punto de usar "../" es que si te fijas hay 5 carpetas antes de llegar al archivo y la pagina tiene mas o menos 20 paginas que se alojan en diferentes partes, la idea es que el archivo tenga una ruta absoluta (cosa que no logro hacer) y que de esa manera el archivo "header.php" lo tome desde cualquier archivo en cualquier carpeta